# Set angular model from MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am following this guide: http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/03/25/bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data-from-aspnet-mvc

This code works fine for me, i.e. I can see the output of @Html.Raw(Model) and it is valid JSON

```
<script>
    angular.module("hobbitModule").value("companionship", @Html.Raw(Model));
</script>
```

However when I run this code

```
var module = angular.module("hobbitModule");
module.controller("CompanionshipController", function($scope, companionship) {
    $scope.companions = companionship;
});
```

The "companionship" variable is always undefined. Here is my version

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
angular.module("myApp.controllers").value("companionship",@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
</script>

ng.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('AccountCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, companionship) {
        $scope.companions = companionship;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding 'companionship' annotation next to $scope into your controller

```
ng.module('myApp.controllers')
.controller('AccountCtrl', ['$scope', 'companionship', function ($scope, companionship) {
    $scope.companions = companionship;
}]);
```